# Return five characters before and after the match in a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple Regex to match 'der' - /der/g
I need the context around the match. Is there any way to build the regex that way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Is there any way* Yes.

Comment: so you want to match everything but `der`?

Comment: `"hellodermate".match(/(.*?)der(.*)/).slice(1)`  would give you `hello` & `mate`

Comment: /.{0,5}der.{0,5}/g  - this worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match the context plus the search string, simply add the optional range before and after the searched string: `.{0,5}der.{0,5}`

If you want to get the context only, you have to fetch it separately: `(.{0,5})der(.{0,5})`

Comment: thank you very much. this was exactly what i was trying to get. you are a hero